# Error while logging in to my remote server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, connection, bashrc

when I try to login to my remote server from the University I get an error as follows:

```
Connection failed. 
Missing }. 
Missing }. }
: Command not found. 
Missing }. 
red255green255blue255: Command not found. 
}: Command not found. 
Missing }. 
}: Command not found. 
margl1440margr1440vieww30480viewh16020viewkind0: Command not found. pardtx720tx1440tx2160tx2880tx3600tx4320tx5040tx5760tx6480tx7200tx7920tx8640pardirnaturalpartightenfactor0: Command not found. Illegal variable name.
```

when I do

```
cat .tcshrc
```

I get

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2513
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww30480\viewh16020\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 alias python="python2.7"\
...
...
...
```

I am seriously clueless!!!! I think there is something wrong with .tcshrc file because I got this error after I edit the `.tcshrc` file. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You're looking at two completely different files - `.tcshrc` and `.bashrc` are **different files** and if you're using Bash you shouldn't be looking at `.tcshrc`.  Are you sure that you edited `bashrc` and not `tcshrc`?

Comment: Did you use a **word processor** program (rather than a text editor) to edit your `.tcshrc` file?

Comment: Yes I am sure I edited `.tcshrc` file. (Realized there was atypo in my question, Sorry about that)

Comment: I realized I used TextEdit tool on my MacBook to edit my `.tcshrc` file